# Elements returns empty string

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I am trying to scrape prices of a website with jSoup, but I only get an empty string.

I've tested my code with [jSoup Online](http://try.jsoup.org/) and I expect `<meta itemprop="price" content="6,99">` to be printed when I use the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements meta = doc.select("meta[itemprop=price]");
System.out.println("meta: " + meta.text());
price = meta.attr("content");
```

However, I just get an empty string and no error. What am I doing wrong here?

For the ones interested I am trying to scrape the price of [this page](https://www.bol.com/nl/p/drinking-games/1001004006154980/?Referrer=ADVNLPPcefb70000000069c007dd7ad51000032610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webserver you are trying to access needs another user agent string to respond with the info you want. Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Element meta = doc.select("meta[itemprop=price]").first();
System.out.println("meta: " + meta.text());
String price = meta.attr("content");
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a NullpointerException on meta: null. However according to jSoup Online I should get the result described in my question.

Comment: Is your URL ok? How did you declare it?

Comment: String URL = ... This should work because I can print the whole page with System.out.println(doc);

Comment: The price variable is already declared before that piece of code. I have tried to simplify the select to just the meta tag and that works. However when I try meta[itemprop] It gives a NullPointer again. According to jSoup Online it should work fine...